# Java program not existing cleanly. Creates Zombies

Tags: java, windows-7, spring-integration, tcp

SCENARIO

I have a java application (uses Spring Integration for Listening on TCP/IP port). 
I am using a few worker threads with an ExecuterService created with  java.util.concurrent.Executors factory.
The main thread creates the worker threads and waits in a loop like follows

```
while(!shutdownRequested)
{
    try {
         Thread.sleep(2000);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
         }
}
```

I have a shutdown hook which stops the executer service and forces shutdown in case of timeout.

PROBLEM
This program does not terminate successfully on my machine (Windows 7). It leaves one thread listening on the tcp port and the process becomes inaccessible after that.
I cannot kill this process from task manager and get an "access denied" error.

It is interesting that this problem happens only my machine and does not affect any other windows 7 machines. On all other machines Control-C from console always stops the program successfully.

I have faced this problem in the past (with the same application) and the problem magically disappeared after I re-formatted and re-installed windows. (i know this was a bit too much!!)

The application worked perfectly for many months untill unfortunately i had to re-format my computer again recently for other reasons. After the re-formatting the problem has come back again.

This is very frustrating as I have to re-start windows every time I need to re-start this application as it cannot bind to the TCP port becuase of the zombie process litening on that port.

Any ideas what could be wrong with my setup?

Comment: I would make sure you have the latest updates for windows as this appears to be an OS bug.

Comment: Thanks Peter for the suggestion but the Windows installation is the same standard image used accross my company and others are not facing this issue!! I have also tried updating my java to latest version.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to [close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close%28%29) the socket.
This will cause the socket to throw a SocketException, and therefore stop blocking.

Comment: Thank you but as I mentioned I am using Spring Integration (to be specific TcpInboundGateway) for communication and do no control the Socket directly. I have , however, tried calling ctx.stop() and ctx.close() and even System.exit(0) to no avail!!. ctx here means spring application context.

Comment: I was going to say you need to stop() the TcpInboundGateway to force it to close the socket. But, stopping the context will already have done that. If System.exit(0) doesn't work then it sounds like it's beyond anything you can do in Java and it's an OS/JVM problem. Can you take a thread dump to see what the errant thread is doing. You can use jstack or VisualVM to get a thread dump. BTW, at least on XP, you can kill a process using drwtsn32 -p [pid] - you can find the pid by enabling that column on TaskManager.